# PDO and Class giving Fatal error: Call to a member function query()

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

I am having some trouble to get database query using below code. I am first time using classes and even PDO for connection so no idea what is wrong. For you knowledge I am not so master but trying to learn class so I would appreciate if you can tell me if anything can improve for this too.

Error Message: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\ pat \ to\ class.php on line 72

```
<?php

    // get database connection
    private static function _db_connect() {

        try {

            $db_con = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name, $db_user, $db_pass);
            $db_con = null;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {

            print "Error!" . $e->getMessage(). "<br/>";

        }

    }


    // get database tables prefix
    public static function prefix() {

        $prefix = 'tb_'; // once done will be set dynamically

        return $prefix;
    }


    // get all users from db
    public static function get_users() {

        $db = self::_db_connect();
        $prf = self::prefix();

        $st = $db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$prf.'users'); // this is the line #72 where error

        while($row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
         $rs[] = $row;

        return count($rs) ? $rs : array();

    }    


?>
```

**EDIT: I have remove null and return PDO object here**

```
    // get database connection
    private static function _db_connect() {

        try {

            $db_con = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name, $db_user, $db_pass);
            return $db_con;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {

            print "Error!" . $e->getMessage(). "<br/>";

        }

    }


    // get database tables prefix
    public static function prefix() {

        $prefix = 'tb_'; // once done will be set dynamically

        return $prefix;
    }


    // get all users from db
    public static function get_users() {

        $db = self::_db_connect();
        $prf = self::prefix();

        $st = $db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$prf.'users'); // this is the line #72 where error

        while($row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
         $rs[] = $row;

        return count($rs) ? $rs : array();

    }    


?>
```

Comment: What is the coding standard that requires an empty row almost for every operator? For a dozen of rows you need to scroll 2 screens down. Is it really convenient for you?

Comment: Truly as I said I never worked with class and PDO so no idea how it works and what exactly code should be there. I just refer some PHP docs and trying to learn and getting error that is why I post my issue here so expert here can guide me what is wrong and how to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning anything from your `db_connect` method, so it returns `NULL` by default. You're trying to call, in essence, `NULL->query()`, which obviously doesn't make sense.

Modify `db_connect` to return the PDO object it creates.

Comment: oops.. stupid mistake.. thnks .. i vil fet back as i chek it.. thanks again

Comment: I have return the PDO object but still giving same error. Please refer my edited code

Comment: You're still having the same error running `query()`, even after returning the PDO object? The only thing I can think of is that your `_db_connect()` method never creates the `$db_*` variables, but I assumed (possibly incorrectly), that you just removed those lines when you posted the code here, since you would have seen other errors if they did not. Please verify that these variables exist with the proper values, and that the PDO object is being created (use `var_dump($db_con)` after you create the object).

Comment: No actually there was a stupid mistake that there was not column in database I was calling. :P I changed column and done. Thanks again for your help.